# ASP.NET display "site down" page instead of YSOD if failure during startup

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to serve a custom "site down" page instead of the standard YSOD if the server were ever to fail during it's startup. Using `<customErrors>` inside of `web.Config` work's fine for any server error occurring after startup has completed successfully, but in this case the YSOD response is not replaced.

Other resources have lead me to adding `app_offline.htm` to the root of the project and playing with its name during deployment, but this does not tackle unexpected server issues occurring during startup.

Is there a way to serve a "default" page if there are any errors or a proper HTTP response could not be formed?

Comment: Please approve this answer if it is helpful so that it can help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to do that but that depends how you want to handle those errors.
If you want to redirect to the same error page on any 4xx or 5xx status codes then you can use the below code in your web.config file

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">
</customErrors>
```

In error page you can display some user friendly message.

Comment: Please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you, so that it can be helpful to others as well